# Are there for-profit observatories?

Tags: amateur-observing, observatory

I'm making a new website for the folks at MIRA.org, and in a bit of curiosity I found myself wondering if there are observatories that are for-profit organizations. What would they even do?

Comment: https://www.itelescope.net/

Comment: [slooh.com](https://www.slooh.com/guestDashboard) "Control The Telescopes; Over 800 time slots to reserve per day"

Comment: https://www.deepskywest.com/ There are lots of these. They have lots of business models.